# What if our body could postpone exertion?

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, biology, physics

Generally, whenever you do physical activities, your body pays with physical energy, and your body experiences exertion. So, if say I ran 100 metres, I would lose some energy and my muscles and organs would accumulate some amount of stress. Now what if I could instantly teleport to the 100 metre mark, then instantly after that by body gets hit with all the energy loss and stress I would have experienced if I run to the 100 metre mark.
Would the human body be able to handle this?

Comment: How do you expect a question that contains the string "by magic" to be answered in a science based way? And what reality are you asking us to do? Magic is not real by definition

Comment: @L.Dutch-ReinstateMonica fixed it. My bad. Still fairly new here.

Comment: @L.Dutch if I have a gun and use magic to double the force behind the bullet with an equal increase in recoil, then you can science-based determine the recoil forces. If you ask how much you can increase the guns magical magnification before it becomes dangerous for a person to hold and fire it (knowing the guntype and ammo type), you can still use science-based methods to determine the answer. Good stories have consistency even in its magic/science fiction elements, and with enough knowledge of their effects can be quantified.

Comment: @Demigan I agree with this completely. My magic is science based so I tend to mix magic with science a lot. That is why I initially added "by magic" to the original question. However, I am fairly new here and I wouldn't wanna break any rules and get my question closed prematurely, that's why I had to take it off ahah.

Comment: @NassKing using magic in your question isnt illegal on this site, but many seem allergic to the notion on this site (L.Dutch is normally not one of them). You can have a perfectly valid question and people will come up with things that are completely besides the point "because you have magic and therefore you can do anything, make your own rules". Yes indeed I make the rules, and I happen to have a question about this specific magical rule and what it would do. I sometimes circumvent it by dressing it up as sci-fi since its essentially the same without saying the M-word.

Comment: @Demigan ahah. That's a nice point. Thanks. I'll try to do that too :)

Comment: You might overheat to death in some activities or suffocate from sudden increase in oxygen required to make the payment. Or heart attacks or aneurysms from increased blood pressure due to blood flow to satisfy that work, energy, and oxygen hitting all at once. Also, a lot of unanswered questions about what boundary energy reserves fall under since they can only be consumed at finite speed. So much hand waving is required you might as well handwave it all

Comment: Note it is complete possible to die through exhaustion, which is going to be a very real problem for your creature since it does not know how exhausted it is getting. -this is going to depend a lot on how the magic works, for instance how does oxygen consumption work with this, what happens when you used more oxygen than the runner has present in their body.

Answer (score 3):

No.

Lets do an example:

I can carry 1 kilogram for 1 hour no problem.

I cant carry 3600 kiligrams for 1 second.

Thats just the stress your body receives. But what about the waste materials?

I can poop a few kilograms in a few seconds.

If I have to poop an entire months worth in a single second, something is going to either clog up or break. Neither is going to be enjoyable. And you basically have the exact same with all your waste products instantly being created and trying to be moved out of the cell, assuming your cells dont explode.

So this is a perfect way to get yourself disabled or dead.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can I ask another related question though? Using your examples, I think this is when you look at it from the extreme side. So what if this is limited to only running? I'm not an expert, but I can't see how getting hit with 50 metres worth of running could kill a person. 100 metres, possibly. I honestly don't know, this is why I ask haha. Can you please explain to me?

Comment: @NassKing it depends on the distance and effort. The fastest 100m sprint is in 9.58 seconds, so 50m would take 5 seconds (assuming you are the world record runner that is). Even standing still as a 70 kilo person and receiving 5 seconds worth of your own weight instantly (lets make that "divided across 1 second")  that means that you'll be carrying 350 kilo's of weight for 1 second (420 actually since you'll get your normal weight too). Now imagine the forces of a fully sprinting man. You are probably better off getting hit by clubs.

Comment: Oh, I understand better now. So, reducing the distance of the hit doesn't make it any safer? I had a rough idea that the farther the person went, the more dangerous this would be. So I felt that anywhere within 5 meters would be negligible. Is this correct?

Comment: It does make it safer, but unfortunately the hit goes up for every second you "travel". How many seconds of sudden movement and weight can you handle? But here magic does come in: you CAN change it. Superstrength and superspeed automatically require resiliance to bullets to make sure the user can survive it, but this is often ignored. It can be assumed they are resiliant to their own effects but normal for other effects (like a bullet). You can say the energy is dissipated differently in a surviveable way.

Comment: I see. That's understandable. Thanks :))